# How to calculate this simple animation effect (physics engine)?

Tags: game-engine, physics-engine

I am implementing a very simple animation effect for a game. The scenario is like this:

1. there is a elastic rubber line, length is 1 meter, when it is extended over 1 meter, it is elastic.
2. the line connects two dots A and B like this, the distance is S, S > 1 meter

A <------------- B

3. then fix dot A, and releases B, the line takes B to the direction of A

I want to know how to calculate time T, which B costs to move X meters towards A (X <= S).

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: hooks law and f = ma, integrate, solve for t

Comment: Haven't done this after high school... get a bit rusty...

Comment: actually i realise its a linear dif. equation y'' + 1/m * k * y = 0, take a look at wolfram alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%2B+1%2Fm+*+k+*+y+%3D+0. this equation governs "simple harmonic motion", so you can search for that if you like

Comment: Seems calculus is needed. Is there a simple formula that I can follow? I searched SHM, and got x=Acos(ωt+φ), so is this the "t" I am looking for? Is there a simple simulated formula for t?

Comment: I am going to try this simulated formula: let speed = sin(x), t = distance / speed, x ranges from 0 to 90 degree.

Comment: the formula for t is fine - if you go to the *full* link (it isn't fomratted correctly) there is the same solution there as sum of sines/cosines. the constants are chosen so that the initial speed is zero, ie just cosine (phi = 0 in your formula), A is chosen as the extent of teh displacement (cos(0) = 0) as w depends on the "springiness" - ratio of mass and elastic constant k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been meaning to learn how to animate these kinds of images in sage (a python based platform for math) for a while, so i used this as an excuse. I hope this code snippet and image is helpful.

```
A = 3
w = 0.5 

# x = f(t) = A cos(wt) inside elastic region
# with x = displacement from 1 meter mark
# in the below code, x is the displacement from origin (x = A cos(wt) + 1)

# find speed when we cross the one meter mark
# f'(t) = -Aw sin(wt), but this is also max speed
# ie f'(t at one meter mark) = -Aw

speed_max = -A * w

# time to reach max speed + time to cross last meter
eta  = float(pi/2 * 1/w + 1/abs(speed_max))

# the function you were looking for
def time_left(x):
    if x < 1:
        return x/abs(speed_max)
    else:
        return 1/w * arccos((x-1)/A)
```

[image]

It may not be clear in the image but within one meter of the origin there is no acceleration.

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome, and stackoverflow is amazing !!

Comment: I tried both 0 - 90 degree (1/4 cycle, speed keeps increasing till the peak), and 0 - 180 degree (1/2 cycle, speed keeps increasing to peak then decreasing to 0). The second one looks more real and natural in the game.